# Recovery password working on localhost but not on hosting side

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have an API created with asp.net and hosted on azure and I'm recovering passwords using an android application created with Xamarin forms. The problem is that I tested the API with Postman and it works(sends recovery email) on localhost but on Azure it doesn't. The API project has SSL activated and I tried using outlook and google and the same behavior happens. I used ports: 587 and 465. Thanks in advance.

API method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("PasswordRecovery")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PasswordRecovery(JObject form)
    {
        try
        {
            var email = string.Empty;
            dynamic jsonObject = form;

            try
            {
                email = jsonObject.Email.Value;
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest("Incorrect call.");
            }

            var user = await db.Users
                .Where(u => u.Correo.ToLower() == email.ToLower())
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext));
            var userASP = userManager.FindByEmail(email);
            if (userASP == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var random = new Random();
            var newPassword = string.Format("{0}", random.Next(100000, 999999));
            var response1 = userManager.RemovePassword(userASP.Id);
            var response2 = await userManager.AddPasswordAsync(userASP.Id, newPassword);

            if (response2.Succeeded)
            {
                var subject = "SIE - Recuperación de contraseña";
                var body = string.Format(@"
                    <h1>Aplicación SIE - Recuperación de contraseña</h1>
                    <p>Tu nueva contraseña es: <strong>{0}</strong></p>
                    <p>Por favor, recuerde cambiarla por una contraseña que sea segura y facil de recordar.",
                    newPassword);

                await MailHelper.SendMail(email, subject, body);
                return Ok(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Esta contraseña no puede ser cambiada.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

here's is the MailHelper class:

```
public class MailHelper
    {
        public static async Task SendMail(string to, string subject, string body)
        {
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            message.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminUser"]);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminUser"],
                    Password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassWord"]
                };

                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPName"];
                smtp.Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
            }
        }

    }
```

and the api service method used on the app

```
public async Task<Response> PasswordRecovery(
            string urlBase,
            string servicePrefix,
            string controller,
            string email)
        {
            try
            {
                var userRequest = new UserRequest { Correo = email, };
                var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);
                var content = new StringContent(
                    request,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json");
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase);
                var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", servicePrefix, controller);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return new Response
                    {
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        Message = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                    };
                }

                return new Response
                {
                    IsSuccess = true,
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new Response
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Message = ex.Message,
                };
            }
        }
```

Postman response:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Wvd.jpg

Comment: Is there any error? Can you show us

Comment: @rjs123431 In postman i'm receiving this message using google: { "Message": "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. } –

Comment: if you are using gmail, you may need to enable "Less secure apps" and make sure your username and password is correct, try to type it directly in your code instead of reading from the config file. Also try `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`

Comment: @rjs123431 I changed smtp server to outlook and it worked on postman, however it didn't on the android application. Through the web I saw that I had to to some changes on the androidmanifest file related to networksecurity config but I don't know if that can be the case.